# Get date-time in seconds from current date

Tags: java, android, datetime

Need to get date-time in seconds from current date.
Want to add 2 days from current date-time and get value of 7 PM of result day.

I.E. 
Current date-time is 1 January, 7:05 PM OR 6:55 PM, I should get value of 3 January, 7:00 PM in seconds.

P.S. - Can't use JODA Time & Java 8.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get date representation in seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106532/get-date-representation-in-seconds)

Comment: yes, tried joda-time but can't use it. Need to have solution using Date / Calendar object of java

Comment: @KaustubhKhare apart from getting value in seconds, I want the value of it at 7 PM of a particular date.

Comment: What prevents you from using Java8 to get this thing done?

Comment: Why would you use `Date` and `Calendar`?  This is like asking for directions, then specifying that you have to go on a horse.

Comment: @MihirPatel I am getting 02 January, 12:35 AM when parsing 1 January, 7:05 PM? is it correct

Comment: no, you should get 3 January, 7 PM. @harshjain

Answer (score 3):

Did you try ThreeTenABP by Jake Wharton? https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP. You can use it also for android versions before api 26 (required for the new java.time.instant) and it has all the functionalities of the Java 8 api.

I would do:

```java
LocalDate myDate;
myDate = LocalDate.now().plus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
LocalDateTime myDateAtTime = myDate.atTime(19,0,0);
long millis = myDateAtTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: Thank you for letting us know about this. +1

Comment: Or if you prefer: `LocalDate.now().plusDays(2)`. Or `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).plusDays(2)` to tell the reader we have chosen the device time zone consciously. May also want the same time zone for `now` and for `toEpochSecond`.

Answer (score 2):

Without using Java 8 you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    System.out.println(c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L); // Time in seconds in two days at 7:00 pm
}
```

You could also create a static method for this:

```
private static long timeInTwoDaysAt7pm() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If java 8 is a no go, then you can use Calendar :

```
import java.util.Calendar

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,  2);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Comment: You're right ! I made some changes. Use add instead of set & set min and sec to 0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a correct approach or any better solution is there.

```
    Date dt = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(dt);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    long timeInSeconds = c.getTime().getTime() / 100;
```

Comment: Note: the time in seconds should be milliseconds divided by 1000 and not 100. 1000 milliseconds is one second after all.

Comment: You don't need the first and third lines.  Other than that, this looks identical to gil.fernandes' answer.

Comment: thanks for your input, will exclude first and third lines. Is is correct other than that ? @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: Well, since it's almost an exact duplicate of someone else's answer, yeah, it's correct.  Apart from dividing by 100 on the last line, which should be 1000.